# Add .phtml file code to admin side made page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout, blocks

I made a page using admin side. and I want to assign this file which I  already used on Product description page . in  `catalog_product_view.xml`

like this

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.details.accessories" template="product/view/accessories.phtml" after="product.info.details" />
```

How I can use this  `accessories.phtml`  now on my page which I made using admin side ?

Answer (score 1):

This is called like:-

```
{{block class="[BlockClassFullName]" template="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]::[YourTemplateFileLocation].phtml"}}
```

For your case will be:-

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]::product/view/accessories.phtml"}}
```

Comment: its in   app/design/frontend/magento/hair/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/accessories.phtml   . So  what will  [VendorName]_[ModuleName]   ?

Comment: Magento_Catalog::product/view/accessories.phtml   ?  like this ?

Answer (score 0):

in cms page you can call template and block by this

```
 {{block class="Your Class" template="your Template Path"}}
```

But in your case this will not work because this class requires `$_product` and this has to be set in this block so in your case if you use this code it will give you fatal error

Comment: So there is no way to get this on admin side @Murtuza